# Typecasting not works for 08 and 09

Tags: python, python-2.7

While typecasting in python I got an error.

```
int(01)
int(02)
int(03)
int(04)
int(05)
int(06)
int(07)
```

Above all works fine.

But when I do same for bellow -:

```
int(08)
```

and

```
int(09)
```

I am getting error i.e

```
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

I know, this typecasting is not correct for converting int to int.

But I just want to know, when it works for 01 to 07, then why it is not working for 08 and 09 only ??

Comment: That is not typecasting.

Comment: Yes, It is not typecasting. because, I am doing for same datatype.

Answer (score 11):

Numbers starting with 0 are considered as octal data. Octal numbers can't have number more than 7.

To fix this, you can convert the data to string and pass the base explicitly like this

```
print int("09", 10)
```

**Output**

```
9
```